# How to exit a trade based on the ATR's LEVEL

Tags: algorithm, pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I'm trying to get my strategy to exit trades as follows

If there is a long TP will occur when:
ATR >=95 & WPR >= -3

If there is a short TP will occur when:
ATR >=95 & WPR <= -93

Not every trade is following the strategy to a T. The WPR is being respected but on occasions a trade will take profit when the ATR is say at 25

This is just a snippet of the code:

```
// Variable declarations for ATR_Normalized & WPR
atrLength = input.int(13, title='ATR Length')
wprLength = input.int(52, title='Williams %R Length')
src = input.source(close, 'Source', group='Williams %R Settings')
atrBuyBreakLevel = input.int(95, title='ATR Buy Breakout Level')
atrSellBreakLevel = input.int(95, title='ATR Sell Breakout Level')
wprBuyBreakLevel = input.float(-3, title='WPR Buy Breakout Level')
wprSellBreakLevel = input.float(-93, title='WPR Sell Breakout Level')

// Calculate ATR and WPR
atrValue = ta.atr(atrLength)
wprValue = ta.wpr(wprLength)

if inTrade    
    entryPrice = strategy.position_avg_price

if strategy.position_size > 0
   if atrValue >= atrBuyBreakLevel and wprValue >= wprBuyBreakLevel 
        strategy.close("Buy", comment = "Take Profit")
        inTrade := false


if strategy.position_size < 0
   if atrValue >= atrSellBreakLevel and wprValue <= wprSellBreakLevel 
        strategy.close("Sell", comment = "Take Profit")
        inTrade := false
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please define your acronyms so the question is self-contained.